# How to decrypt a WF_Decrypt

Tags: java, oracle

An Oracle iProcurement sends my webservice a cXML message. In this message there is also a `<SharedSecret>`. Oracle decrypts this to a `WF_Decrypt`, for example:

```
<SharedSecret>
    #WF_DECRYPT#_@94$^@234s34342349^4@04!680`8B#+B%0}@}8&@9A^#WF_DECRYPT#
</SharedSecret>
```

My webservice, which catches this cXML, is built with Java. Can someone explain me, what `WF_Decrypt` is, and how to accept this in Java?

Answer (score 2):

From what I gathered, WF stands for Oracle Workflow, which is somehow related to iProcurement. The shared secret is not sent in the clear, but is encoded for additional security. I am quite sure that the encryption can be turned off somehow, however IMHO that's a bad idea.

You will need to contact Oracle on this matter, though I have a guess, that you will need to use some Oracle component in your webservice implementation.